# Heartbleed bug and Altcoins

Tags: security, altcoin

Bitcoin recently released V 0.9.1 patching vulnerabilities from the Heartbleed bug, however I have not seen anything from any alt coin. What are the possible security risks associated with using these coins? And what are the risks to the coins themselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done a little research on this as it was a big concern, not to worry! This is only an issue if you have a bitcoin (or altcoin) daemon set up with RPC over HTTPS. This would only be used if say, you have a daemon running on one VPS and another node which asks it to send money. Source: http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/news/openssl-heartbleed-security-bug/2014/04/08

This is disabled by default and unless you were using RPC over SSL there is no need to worry :)

If you have been using RPC for any coin I would say a good practice would be to generate a new wallet and send funds there.